# Do I Need My #include Directives In My Headers?

Tags: c++, c, header, include

Do I need to include everything in my header that I include in the source file? For instance, I have a file called source.cpp that starts with:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
```

Then I have a header called source.hpp that only includes string. This compiles just fine, but is this bad practice, or could it lead to complications in the future?

Comment: There's no way for us to know. It depends on your headers. Include what you need, and no more.

Comment: I always try to include the absolute minimum in headers because of compile times. It may not save much time for programs with a few hundred lines of code however several of my projects are a few hundred thousand lines with thousands of source files and thousands of headers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some headers that the source file needs may be just for implementation details, so no, there's no need to `#include` them in the header as well.

The rule I follow is this: `#include` only what you absolutely need in the header file, then in the source file, `#include` all files the the header file includes, plus additional needed headers for implementation details.

In case anyone's wondering, the reason I copy all `#include` directives from the header into the source file is that, in case I later replace one of those directives in the header with a forward declaration, my source file doesn't need to change at all.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I figured I should make sure just in case.

Answer (score 2):

I usually include what is strictly necessary for a given file.

If your header uses the string type, then add an `#include <string>`. The same for the code. In general headers are guarded so it is both harmless and interestingly expressive (no need to dig in headers/code to determine what is necessary).

Answer (score 1):

The header definitely does not need all the `#include`s that the cpp needs. Moreover, I think such practice should be discouraged, and in some cases it can even be impossible.

I think that your header should have what is needed for the header itself and **only that** (i.e. the header should have as little `#include`s as possible), and you `cpp` that has all the additional `#include`s. Also note that there is no need to repeat the `#include`s from the header in the cpp provided that cpp `#include`s the header.

For your example, I would have

```
#include <string>
```

in the header, and

```
#include "source.hpp"  // automatically includes string
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
```

Note also that forward declarations can further minimize the amount of `#include`s in header.

Answer (score 0):

No need to include everything you had in your header file. Put what ever **needed**
in your header file and just include the header file in .cpp file.
More better is to use forward declarations in your header file. That way you may avoid unnecessary compilations.

Comment: The question is about whether `#include` directives in the source file need to be present in the header file as well, not the other way around.

Comment: @RedRoboHood, IMO this answer exactly answers the question stated.

Comment: @Petr Then upvote it. I disagree with you, but there's no way I can change your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend to MINIMIZE #includes for production code.

Especially in header (.hh) files.

Even more so in 'popular' header files (header files pulled in thousands of times, use grep or find).

Even to the extent of using

- external / forward declaration of classes, structs, etc. instead of include (by using references or pointers inside the header file) and
- double 'guards' on include files (#ifdef guards in both where-included and  in-the-header-file) and
- refactoring the "very popular" include headers (even when an inspection does not identify 'poor cohesion' of contents).

Reason:

I have worked with large builds (i.e. 100 to 1000 KLOCs).
A poor attitude w.r.t. header-file-includes has remarkable loading effects on the build network and servers, thus affecting ALL your team's productivity.

More than once I have measured (using '-H' and C++ map and wc) byte count numbers (of chars) well into the mulitple-terrabytes ... to do one build.  A huge load on shared network and shared file servers.

- In that environment, an early morning build might take 40 minutes.
- Around noon on busy week days, the 200+ developers generally went to a long lunch because the build took 3 to 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , one can certainly improve the programming skills,
we can use `#include"string"` ,

```
#include<string>
```

So that you can avoid the data that is not going to be used. Only the fewer data is inserted from the Header File and not all the content.